# Screen sharing option missing from Ubuntu 18.04 (vino installed)

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop

I have a computer on Ubuntu 18.04 (actually upgraded from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04). I need to set up screen sharing but the option isn't there.

In settings > sharing, the master sharing switch is on and I see computer name, but underneath that only Remote login and File sharing - no option for screen sharing as the docs suggest it should be.

As per the title, vino is installed - maybe there's another package I need that somehow didn't transition between the two versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is old, but here's an answer:

Log out, and then start the login (select your user name) but before you enter your password, click the gear-icon...then select the "Ubuntu with Xorg" and NOT the "Ubuntu" option.

Log in, and go back to Sharing...you should see "Screen Sharing" there now.

Comment: I only see Ubuntu with wayland..

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, only "Ubuntu with wayland" available, and that does not cure the problem

Comment: In 19.04 after clicking the gear icon pick the "Ubuntu" option. You can then enable sharing, including "Screen Sharing" via Settings (`gnome-control-center sharing`).

Answer (score 3):

Screen sharing requires `vino` package installation per [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en).

[image: screen grab]

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
2. dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption false
3. /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable start
4. see "settings --> sharing" again

Comment: Why is that `dconf` command necessary?

Comment: for windows connections mostly. not very secure